# Не распознаются руские буквы при вводе с клавиатуры C++ Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Только начал  изучать с++. Проблема вот в чем: русский текст в самом коде распознает. а вот при запросе ввода с клавиатуры получается ерунда.
програмка простенькая до безобразия. Дан список профессий запрашивается ввод первой буквы профессии (на русском), затем[image: определение английского символа] выводится на экран название профессии полностью.[скрин программы и результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHwTX.png)[image: неопределение русского символа]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

////////////////////////////////////
enum etype { rabochiy, sekretar, menedger, bugalter, direktor, ucheniy };
////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    etype tip;
    unsigned char ch;
    cout << "Введите первую букву профессии" << endl
         << "(Рабочий, секретарь, менеджер, бугалтер, директор, ученый): ";
    cin >> ch;
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 'р': tip = rabochiy; break;
        case 'с': tip = sekretar; break;
        case 'м': tip = menedger; break;
        case 'б': tip = bugalter; break;
        case 'д': tip = direktor; break;
        case 'у': tip = ucheniy; break;
        default: cout << "Неверный ввод!!"; exit(0); break;
    }
    switch (tip)
    {
        case rabochiy: cout << "Вы выбрали профессию РАБОЧИЙ" << endl;  break;
        case sekretar: cout << "Вы выбрали профессию СЕКРЕТАРЬ" << endl; break;
        case menedger: cout << "Вы выбрали профессию МЕНЕДЖЕР" << endl; break;
        case bugalter: cout << "Вы выбрали профессию БУГАЛТЕР" << endl; break;
        case direktor: cout << "Вы выбрали профессию ДИРЕКТОР" << endl; break;
        case ucheniy: cout << "Вы выбрали профессию УЧЕНЫЙ" << endl; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите, чему у Вас становится равно `ch` после ввода

Comment: И приведите, пожалуйста, код программы текстом, а не картинкой, чтобы участники сообщества могли его запустить для тестирования

Comment: При введении "р"   ch равен 224 'а'. Если заменить символы для ввода на английские то все работает без проблем

Comment: Добавил в код пару строчек  system("chcp 1251");
 system("cls");  теперь символы русского языка вводятся и выводятся правильно, но проблема осталась если ввести русский символ такой же как в switch один фиг не хочет сравниваться. И заметил такую штуку если символы заменить на английские  при наведении курсора выскакивает контекстное меню с этим символом, а с русскими символами в меню только знак вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Потестил Ваш код и нашёл решение. Уберите `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");`. Видимо, в новых версиях VS  в нём нет необходимости.

Comment: Без этой строчки вообще беда... вместо русского вылазит абракадабра. На сколько я смог понять проблема в кодировке, беда в том что я не знаю что добавить в код чтоб все заработало или какие настройки поменять. И вообще подскажите болвану как посмотреть символы таблицы ASCII. ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!!!! Стою на месте не могу дальше учиться аж бесит

Comment: @ВаняКалиновский, [ascii](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (возможно в винде стоит смотреть [cp1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251))